# Nuance between して遊ぶ and just する

Tags: word-choice, nuances

When you have a する verb for something that is a game, it seems like you can alternatively have して遊ぶ. What I want to know is what nuance this has. For example, what is the difference between:

- トランプをする and トランプをして遊ぶ
- テニスをする and テニスをして遊ぶ

Comment: Xして遊ぶ  is just Xして + 遊ぶ, where して is the te-form (connective form) of する。In your examples, 遊ぶ is the main verb, and it should be clear enough what the meaning is (and thus the difference in nuance) by considering that verb by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the difference between both is that, by using して遊ぶ, it's explicit that the ones playing video games are having fun, enjoying themselves.

> テニスをする
>
> > He plays tennis

> テニスをして遊ぶ
>
> > He has fun playing tennis.

Comment: Ah okay. So if, for example, someone doesn't enjoy Tennis but is forced to play it by their friends or whatever, you couldn't say テニスをして遊ぶ?

Comment: @MegaZeroX Yes, that's correct simply because he doesn't enjoy tennis: you cannot have fun doing something you don't enjoy.